# Paypal Integration with PHP

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

I am using this code to create my subscription for PayPal.
But it is not recognizing any of my input fields. Would you be able to shed some light on why not?

```
<form method="POST" name="gateway_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="EMAIL"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.URL.com/payment/paypal_success.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.URL.com/payment/paypal_failure.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.URL.com/payment/paypal_ipn.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Monthly Subscription"/>
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="0.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="49.00"/>

<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"/>
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="30"/>
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="1"/>

<input type="submit" value="Click Here"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link:

**Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables**

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside

Also, I suggest you use a hosted button. It makes the whole process very easy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell PayPal who is submitting the request by submitting the required URL parameters user, pwd, version, and (recommended but optional) signature, along with the other parameters you're sending in the POST request.  See [API Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview#id09C2F0A0GQN).

Answer (score 0):

Well both you guys were right, but the issue that came about was because on my 3rd line there

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
```

needs to become

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"/>
```

Thanks for your help!